# Can I board a closed-loop cruise to Alaska with a Canadian port call, with just a US Green card?

Tags: usa, passports, canada, cruising

I am a US Permanent Resident and I booked a cruise to Alaska. It is a closed loop cruise starting and ending in on Seattle, WA. It has one stop in Canada which is Victoria,Canada

I just realized that my wife's passport expired last month. I thought that it would be okay since her Green Card is still valid. The last time we visited Canada I had my Green Card and I don't think I carried my passport. We are going to submit a passport renewal application, but I am not sure it will be renewed in time.

The [USCIS link](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1139/~/documents-needed-to-take-a-cruise) says that people do not have to carry a passport if they are a US citizen and are on a closed loop cruise.

In our case, we are Permanent Residents, not citizens; would our Green Card be fine? If not, what is the final authority that decides if we can travel, or if we could even attempt it?

Do Canadian officials know who is on the ship, or it is just cruise ship staff? Who has final authority to deny our entry on the cruise? What is the best way to approach the situation?

Comment: The cruise staff (or the staff they contract to check people in at the port) are the final authority. If you don't meet their requirements, you're not boarding, regardless of government rules.

Comment: Where does your cruise start and end? What is your citizenship?

Comment: My cruise starts and ends in Seatle, WA. I am an Indian citezen with US permenent residency

Comment: Then Canadian officers are irrelevant. If you don't get off the ship in Canada, you will have no problems with Canadian immigration. Your only problem will be getting back into the US. Talk to US immigration and the cruise line staff and see if they will let you on.

Comment: @DJClayworth green card holders don't generally need a passport to enter the US Unless they're flying in, under the Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative

Comment: Does the cruise stop at any Canadian ports?

Comment: cruise stops at one canadian port

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think that's necessarily true. Even if you don't get off the ship in Canada, the cruise line is still responsible for processing you through immigration behind the scenes. For example, if you're a national of a country where a visa is required to travel to Canada, you wouldn't normally be allowed on the cruise if you just said "oh I won't get off in Canada." Of course, in this case, green card holders can enter Canada with just their green card, but the point is that the foreign country matters even if you don't get off the ship.

Comment: What cruise line are you sailing?

Comment: @zach I am sailing with `Holland America`

Comment: @ZachLipton On a Princess Alaskan cruise that had a stop at a Canadian port, they would not board anyone without a passport and/or visa for Canada (if necessary). They did not care if you planned to disembark at that port or not.

Comment: @Coke perhaps so.  I took a few domestic flights in Canada and they made much of a "government-issued ID" requirement, at boarding, for those over 18.  It seemed rather new.  I didn't pay attention to the details so I don't know whether a green card would be acceptable.

Comment: Missing information in question: does the ship have any stop in Canada? Presumably yes, based on your details.

Comment: @phoog I now see that your original comment implied that a passport is needed for green Card holders to enter **the US**, which isn't the case. Now you said Canada though, which does require a passport and eTA to enter by air

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK this is not an answer as in if this is how it legally works. However, this is what happened when I traveled on `Holland America cruiseline` with expired passport and a valid GreenCard

1. When boarding the cruise-ship the officer who was responsible for checking our documents acknowledged that the passport is expired but that is fine since the Green Card is valid and we were able to board the cruiseship without any problems
2. When disembarking in `Victoria,Canada` they asked us to fill a form where we need to provide passport information of one family member(normally head of the family) and we provided my passport information(which was not expired)
3. When we came back to U.S. officer did check only our GC(he checked the passport but did not even bother to mention expired date on the Passport)

Now, we could be extremely lucky that we did not face much scrunity but just for extra preparation I printed out some documentation which I hope may help:

- https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1139/~/documents-needed-to-take-a-cruise
- https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents

Now, question is when `Holland America Website` explicitly mentioned that we need the passport then why did they not ask?

First of all I think they have a very generalized guidelines for `just-in-case` scenarios. The officer who checks our documents at the port is not actually Holland America. That officer is either CBP or in our case they hired a contracting company approved by CBP. So the final authority is the officer on the port which is affiliated with CBP. However, printing the supporting docs helps

Comment: What year was that? Was it recent? Things change all the time.

Comment: This was July 2017

Comment: "they asked us to fill a form where we need to provide passport information of one family member" -> that's the customs declaration and you don't actually need a passport to fill it out, as you can enter Canada with just the Green Card.

Answer (score 7):

[Holland America's travel documents say](https://www.hollandamerica.com/assets/cruise-vacation-onboard/KBYG.pdf):

> **For Non-U.S./Non-Canadian Citizens:**
>
> You must have and carry a  passport valid for six months beyond the
>   duration of your travel.  Please carefully verify the existing
>   identification requirements for  your particular travel situation. In
>   addition, non-U.S. citizens who have  previously been admitted to the
>   United States for permanent residence  must carry their Permanent
>   Resident Card (Form I-551), commonly  known as a Green Card. Resident
>   aliens not in possession of this must  obtain one at the nearest
>   office of the U.S. Immigration Service.
>
> [...]
>
> Guests are responsible for verifying and obtaining any necessary 
>   travel documents for entry and exit to the countries visited, as 
>   these requirements vary depending on the specific port and 
>   nationality of the traveler. This includes payment of all costs related 
>   to arrangements to obtain entry to the countries you visit. Boarding 
>   may be denied or fines levied against those guests arriving at the 
>   pier without the proper documentation, and those guests will not be 
>   eligible for a refund. 
>   Payment of any fines levied is the responsibility 
>   of the individual guest. Please note that fees and visa requirements 
>   are subject to change without notice.

In short, you must have a passport valid for six months beyond the duration of your travel and a green card with you if you're not a US or Canadian citizen. No exception is listed for permanent residents to travel without a passport. That's the cruise line's rule regardless of any government regulations that would allow you to travel with less. The cruise line is the final authority that determines whether you can board, and it can make its own rules about travel documents.

You can always contact the cruise line, but if they tell you that you can travel, I'd want that in writing, and you're still entirely at the mercy of the staff at the port, who could refuse you boarding anyway.

Comment: I actually called Holland America this morning and they said that they will  defer to the Custom officer's discretion at the port. So now the question is that if it is worth trying to convince Custom officer with all the supporting documentation from USCIS.

Comment: @TeaLeave don't trust a random person on the phone - always get everything in writing

Comment: The person who checks you in, often a contractor, will follow whatever rules they've been given by Holland America. If their little handbook says you need a passport, then you need a passport, and they're not going to care if you say someone on the phone told you otherwise. If you're going to attempt to board without a passport, you absolutely need something in writing from the cruise line.

Comment: Ok so I called the cruise-line and they said that the `custom-immigration-officer` on the port decides everything and they don't have a say into this matter. I called CBP(Airport NOT seaport because there is no direct seaport number). The CBP officer said ONLY GC is fine. However, she cannot speak for the `seaport` authorities

Comment: I would not trust the cruise-line. Check any consumer complaints website and you'll see a lot of incidences of people being told the wrong visa/passport information over the phone by cruise companies and then literally left at the dock.

Comment: You Need to **E-Mail** Holland America, and if they say it's up to the CBP, E-Mail the CBP. Then get **both** answers in writing

Comment: Has anyone ever declared themselves stateless while on a cruise? Possibly after concealing or destroying their passport?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Seattle Times](http://www.seattletimes.com/life/travel/you-may-want-passport-for-cruise-to-alaska/):

> For “closed-loop” sailings such as Seattle-Alaska cruises that depart
> and return to the same U.S. port, U.S. officials say that a passport
> or one of the new alternative documents isn’t required — that a birth
> certificate and government-issued photo ID, such as a driver’s
> license, are sufficient (those documents are needed to prove both a
> traveler’s identity and citizenship). However, some cruise lines
> strongly urge cruise passengers to have passports. So check — and
> double-check — with your cruise line. (And you must have ID even if
> you’re not planning to get off the ship in Victoria.)

So I'm interpreting it as you do not need a passport since your cruise is "closed-loop". If it were me, I would bring the expired passport just in case. If you don't get off the ship in Canada, then you shouldn't have a problem.

But you should check with Holland America just to be safe.

Comment: The closed loop is not the relevant part; that simply means that it departs and returns to the same port (US). OP notes that there is a Canadian port call. For that, those who are not US or Canadian citizens require a valid passport or visa to enter Canada, with the exception of US Lawful Permanent Residents who may use their I-551 (Green Card)  instead of a passport.

Comment: [I don't think there is a big problem getting off the ship in Canada with a valid green card](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16), nor is returning to the US a problem. His only issue is making sure the cruise line sees it that way too.

Comment: @Dorothy: what you just said, is it somewhere on USCIS website?

Comment: @ZachLipton You're correct, I overlooked that part. Answer edited.

Comment: @TeaLeave, USCIS may not have much of an opinion on what is required to enter Canada by sea, you need to rely on a Canadian source for that. The [CBP is unambiguous that a green card alone is necessary and sufficient to reenter the US](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents) but also points out that your transportation company may have requirements beyond the CBP's. It is the latter that you need to worry about, only the cruise company will know what they require.

Comment: A quick read establishes clearly that your quoted paragraph is talking about US citizens.